# CanCan(Can) and Activeadmin: Index on nested relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan, cancancan

I am using CanCan(Can) together with ActiveAdmin.  However, I am seriously struggling to get CanCan(Can) to work properly on index for a “has_many through” relationship.

Basically my Invoice model looks like this

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :currency

  has_one :user, :through => :order
(…)
```

My order model like this

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :invoices
```

And my user model like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders
  has_many :invoices, :through => :orders
```

My abilities are defined like this

> can :read, Invoice, :user => adminuser.user

This works fine on individual invoices.  So the right user can see this URL :3000/admin/invoices/1 while other users will get a not authorized error.

However on the index listing it goes south completely. :3000/admin/invoices/ returns the error message

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'invoices.user_id' in 'where clause':
>   SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM
>   `invoices`  WHERE `invoices`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0)
>   subquery_for_count

Obviously this is completely wrong as CanCan(Can) is looking at the wrong table. How do I set ActiveAdmin and CanCan(Can) to use a “through” lookup for this relationship on index?  I have tried adding

```
def authorize_access!
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :order
end
```

to the controller of “ActiveAdmin.register Invoice” but it made no difference.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `can :read, Invoice, :user => { :id => adminuser.user.id }`